# ошибка в Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Здравствуйте хочу сделать запрос к базе данных с помощью hibernate, выдает ошибку
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: article is not mapped [from article],
вот код бина:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; 
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Date;
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="aricleName")
private String aricleName;

@Column(name="content")
private String content;

@Column(name="publicationdate")
private Date date;

@Column(name="category")
private String category;

public Article() {

}

public Article(String aricleName, String content,String category,Date date) {
    this.aricleName = aricleName;
    this.content = content;
    this.category=category;
    this.date=date;
}
public String getCategory(){
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category){
    this.category=category;
}
public Date getDate(){
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date){
    this.date=date;

}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAricleName() {
    return aricleName;
}

public void setAricleName(String aricleName) {
    this.aricleName = aricleName;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + aricleName + ", lastName=" + content + "]";
}
```

}

вот как я запускаю:

```
import java.util.List;
import news.Article;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import sqloperations.SqladdArticleOperation;
public class sadq {
public static void main(String [] args){

SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Article.class).buildSessio
nFactory();
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<Article>articles =
                session.createQuery("from article").list();
}
}
```

подскажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: Может "from Article" сработает? В JPA например в качестве имен сущностей используется имя класса, которое как известно регистрозависимое.

Comment: да именно так и работает спасибо за помощь